# how to get data from array in the table in separate variable

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This is my output of an array when i dump it. I want every value in an individual variable. Can any one help like in a tabular form? it should show all domains like new.com (showing all domains).

```
{
"Google-Yahoo": {
    "com": "available",
    "net": "notavailable"
     "org": "notavailable"
},
"GoogleSite": {
    "com": "available",
    "net": "notavailable"
    "org": "notavailable"
},
"Deal-Seek": {
    "com": "available",
    "net": "notavailable"
    "org": "notavailable"
},
"Love-Seek": {
    "com": "available",
    "net": "available"
    "org": "notavailable"
},
"True-Seek": {
    "com": "available",
    "net": "available"
   "org": "notavailable"
}
}
```

Comment: i tried `foreach($details as $domain){
 echo $domain['com']."</br>";
echo $domain['net']."</br>";
echo $domain['org']."</br>";

 foreach($domain as $new_array){
  //echo $new_array;
  }
 }
`

Comment: Isnt an array, is an object with objects inside. Even you can use a foreach http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.iterations.php using key=>value

Answer (score 0):

use object notation rather than array notation.

```
foreach($details as $domain){ 
    echo $domain->com."</br>"; 
    echo $domain->net."</br>"; 
    echo $domain->org."</br>"; 
    etc...
```

Your result is not an array, it is an object.